# How do I make a MySQL statement from ID to ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Example I have 500 users and every 50 users manage by one moderator.

Let's say `moderator_id = 1` can edit/manage user from `user_id` 1 until 50. What is the statement should I use?

```
SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE 
  user_id `what should i use here?` 
  AND 
  moderator_id = '1';
```

Let me know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `BETWEEN` operator, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 50
AND moderator_id = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm prefer to use an additional column with the moderator_id. In that case you can dynamically change user's set for each moderators without changing anything in the code.

To initially define user's set per moderator use query like that:

```
UPDATE users
SET moderator_id = 1
WHERE user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

To select users by moderator use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE moderator_id = 1
```